# What is the difference between RO-Properties and TO-Properties in QTP?

Tags: qtp

In QTP each test object supports the following methods

```
GetRoProperty
GetToProperty
SetToProperty
GetToProperties
```

What is the difference between a **RO**-property and a **TO**-property and why can I only set a **TO**-property and not an **RO**-property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between **RO**-Properties and **TO**-Properties are that **TO** properties refer to the properties as they exist in the Test Object saved in the test (i.e. in the object repository or as described in descriptive programming) and the **RO**-Properties refer to the RunTime object (i.e. the object as it appears in the Application Under Test (AUT)).

From this distinction a few things arise

1. Accessing a **TO** property doesn't require the AUT to be open
2. Accessing an **RO** property requires the AUT to be open and the object to be uniquely described
3. You can set the value of a **TO** property but not that of an **RO** property

In addition to the QTP specific properties some technologies also support accessing the native object's properties via the `.Object` property of the test object.

Comment: While training a colleague of mine on QTP, he came up with a great analogy which encapsulates the difference between `TO` and `RO`. `TO` is like a police description of the suspect being sought. `RO` would be analogous to the actual person matching that description.

Answer (score 0):

please find the below difference between [GetRoProperty , GetToProperty, GetTOProperties](http://qtp-interviewquestions.blogspot.in/) :

GetTOProperty : (Get Test Object Property) :  GetTOProperty can be used to fetch a particular test object property from object repository.

`GetTOProperties` : `GetTOProperties` is used to enumerate all the properties of an object used for identification.

`GetROProperty` : (Get Runtime Object Property)

`GetROProperty` is used to fetch the property value of an object at runtime.

Let's take an example :

Suppose there is link present on some webpage and we have to verify the text of the link at runtime,

```
sLinkText = Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").Link("html tag:=a","visible:=true").GetROProperty("innertext")
msgbox sLinkText
```

output:

```
Gmail
```

Similarly, we can fetch any property of any particular object at run time.