# Using function to test a dynamic value

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm new to UFT and I recently finished the tutorial. My question is, in the tutorial we check the departure date , but it only works if we choose this date (if it's another date, the object date is not find in the page).

Is there a way to get back a field in the page and then check its format? I would like to try it on my website on a field "last visit: MM/DD/YYYY at HH/MM" but I couldn't find how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like maybe the specific date has somehow found it's way into the properties of the test object - such that when the date is different, the test object can't be found.

If that's the case, you would fix it by editing the properties of the test object - open the object repository (CTRL-R), find the object, and check what properties the object was recorded with.  Edit the properties to remove the overly specific part, such that the object can be identified regardless of what date is shown.

once you get that fixed, you should be able to pull the date the RO object is displaying by querying the property.

For more information on (and how to understand) TO vs RO objects, see my answer to this question: [What is the difference between Test Objects and Runtime Objects in QTP? Is the given explanation correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512875/what-is-the-difference-between-test-objects-and-runtime-objects-in-qtp-is-the-g/36163368#36163368)

Comment: Exactly, in both the tutorial and my example, the innertext property contains the date. I've tried to use a text checkpoint to get my date by his properties but didn't work. Thanks for your answer, I will read your link

Comment: You can (and should) convert the innertext property of the test object to a Regular Expression, and then where the date appears, change those characters to .*      That would be the easiest fix...  Just make sure you test your object with the "highlight in application" button after you make the change.  Ideally, it should "find" the object no matter what date is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I will try that

Comment: BTW - once you are able to reliably "find" the object/control and extract the date displayed on it, you can then pass that date to a UDF in a function library for validation :)  Personally, I like using Regex to validate strings.

Comment: It works! With regex in the innertext of my object it now recognize all the "last visit" and I can get the real value with "GetROProperty("innertext")". Just some warnings ("The object has been detected by the description of the test object") but I will be able to test the format. Thanks!