# How to use getoproperty in UFT

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

In my application when I click on save a reference no will be generated.it will keep on changing on every time application runs.I want to get this reference no in qtp report

Reference no is shown on a webelement.I stored the webelement in object repository with name 'reference'

My code is

```
Dim refernceno,test
test="001"
refernceno=browser("abc").page("abc"). Webelement ("reference"). Getroproperty ("reference")
Reporter.ReportEvent micpass,"Test passed"&test,"Reference"&refernceno
```

But the result shown is only Test passed 001

No reference no is showing

Kindly suggest how to use getroproperty

Comment: You're using reference twice here, once as the name of the `WebElement` in the repository and once as the parameter to `GetROProperty`. Please try to clarify your question so we can help you. Perhaps another one of my answers will help you in understanding properties in UFT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699160/what-is-the-difference-between-ro-properties-and-to-properties-in-qtp

Answer (score 0):

`GetROProperty` is used to fetch the set of properties defined by UFT from the object in the application. You can see these properties by using the object spy.

UFT allows you to access the Web DOM attributes by using the `attribute/` syntax in `GetROProperty` (and other places).

Try:

```
refernceno = Browser("abc").Page("abc").Webelement("Reference").GetROProperty("attribute/reference")
```